# Catholic Church's position on catholic husband and muslim wife

Tags: catholicism, marriage, islam

I am a Spanish Catholic guy and I met a Russian girl from the Caucasus who is a Muslim (although not practicing).

Her family is Muslim culturally, none of them pray or wear hyjab or similar, but they practice Ramadan, for example.

I am convinced **I want to marry her**.

Am I committing a sin?

Should I try to reconvert her if she is willing or would this not be right?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not the site to ask personal advice.  I highly recommend you talk to your confessor / priest about your specific situation.  Please also consider whether your girlfriend is willing to convert to be Catholic as the issue of nurturing your future children's faith life is extremely important and a unified faith of their parents is essential.

Comment: Having similar values with regard to religion is an important predictor of a successful marriage. Have you talked about your differences with your girlfriend?

Comment: @GratefulDiscipleThank you for the tip!

Comment: @DJClayworth Yeah, we talked about it and we have the same vision, project and life goals, same values and same "ideology", just she believes in other religion. She said me that we believe in the same good, only with a different perspective ... Do you think could we have a successful marriage in the eyes of the church? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know you, and couldn't possibly give you a good answer. My sole reason for making the comment was to encourage you to consider the issue. If you are unsure I would maybe talk to someone in your religious communities or a marriage guidance counsellor. I wish you all the best.

Comment: @DJClayworth Thank you! Is what I will do! Thank you again, god bless you!

Comment: In my parish there is a devout Catholic woman who is married to a Muslim man. To answer your question, as a Catholic you are not committing a sin if you marry her so long as you receive the proper dispensations from your local bishop or his delegate.

Comment: Thank you! I will have faith! @Jeh